# Select datetime according to HH:MM condition

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with `event` and `datetime`. How can I simply select all events that occurred any day before 21:15 hr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`TIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function to get just the time portion of a DateTime column and do the comparison that way:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE TIME(dateColumn) < '21:15:00';
```

A full list of useful MySQL date and time functions can be found at [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html), which may be helpful for other comparisons in the future.